# How do I add a floating form

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have a program with one form. I want to have a new form that floats above the existing form and interacts with it to do things like get files, write files, run subs, etc. I've found several similar "how to's" but none with enough info for a novice like me. Also, when I tried to declare Dim myForm as New FloatingForm() it doesn't accept it. I need to know specifically step by step how to create the new floating form (Do I add a new form to my project?) and where to put the code (and what is the code) to make it appear and float and then to make it go away and to bring it back.

Comment: I think you're looking for a non-modal form.

Comment: _it doesn't accept it_ is not acceptable. Are you getting a compile-time error or a runtime error, and what is the error? If you don't know how to figure this out, then your question should be addressed on a different forum than StackOverflow.

Comment: Presumably you are using Winforms; if that is the case, add that as a tag to your question.